# ArrayList Search in BlueJ

Tags: java, class, arraylist, bluej

Trying to get back into using Java now that school has picked up again and I'm having a lot of trouble getting a method to work properly between two classes.

I have a "Family" class and a "Member" class and I need to make sure each member has a different unique ID when they are added to the family.  So far I have:

```
public class Family
{
private ArrayList <Member> FamilyMembers;

...

public Family()
{
    FamilyMembers = new ArrayList<Member>();
}

....

public ArrayList getMembers()
{
    return FamilyMembers;    
}

}
```

and

```
public class Member
{
private int ID;

...

public Member(int newID, String newMemberName, String newSex)
{
    this.ID = newID;

...

}

 public void setID(int newID)
{  

    boolean unique = true;
    for(Member m: Family.getMembers())
      {
       if(m.getID()==newID)
        {
          unique=false;
        }
       }
    if(true)
     {
        this.ID = newID;
     }
}
```

When I compile I get the error that a non-static method getMembers cannot be referenced from static context?  I don't understand why I can't use the get method from my Family class to perform a search before setting an ID?  Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the method:

```
public ArrayList getMembers()
{
    return FamilyMembers;    
}
```

is not static entails you need to create an object of the Family class to call up the above method. You can do one of two things.

1. Add the word static as follows:

   public static ArrayList getMembers().
2. Or you could just create an object of the class as follows.
   insert this code.

   Family ob = new Family();

ob is the object. Now you can use it to call up the method as follows:

```
ob.getMembers();
```

In your code it will look like this:

```
for(Member m: ob.getMembers())
```

Comment: Going with both of the solutions here I tried to put just "static in front of the method, but then in the loop I was unable to "find symbol - variable Family".

If I make a new Family in the method, I receive an error about incompatible types:

     public void setID(int newID)
     {  
        boolean unique = true;
        Family f = new Family();
        for(Member m: f.getMembers())
        {
            if(m.getID()==newID)
            {
                unique=false;
            }
        }
      ...
    }
(Sorry I can't figure out how to mark code in comment)

Comment: Could you be clear please, I didn't understand why you tried to convey.Did my solutions work for you?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I was trying to show what results I had with either option.  Neither way was able to compile and do what I needed to do.

Comment: Did you obtain a solution

Comment: Not as of yet.  I just said though "neither way compiled and did what I needed to".  I think what you suggested is on the correct track and I'll try some more things later.

Comment: Good luck, please show solution on post when obtained

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Family` instance to call `getMembers()` on. So this,

```
for(Member m: Family.getMembers())
```

Should be something like (or pass the instance, `f` below, in),

```
Family f = new Family();
for(Member m: f.getMembers())
```

Comment: That clears up a bit of the trouble I was having earlier with getting methods from other classes to be called in a different class thanks! 

But if I did something along those lines, wouldn't I also still have to generate an ArrayList inside of the Family by calling it's constructor  And the ID would only be unique in that one Family?